# How to debug null properties sent through on form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following form in my view for model `@model SharedLibrary.Sample`:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Send", "Sample", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.QCDate, Model.QCDate)

    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.GRV, Model.GRV)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.Pallet, Model.Pallet)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.PONo, Model.Pallet.Grv.PONo)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.PalletSeq, Model.Pallet.PalletSeq)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.SampleNo, Model.SampleNo) 

    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.Clerk, Model.Clerk)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.Supervisor, Model.Supervisor)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.StatusClerk, Model.StatusClerk)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.StatusSupervisor, Model.StatusSupervisor)

    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.QtyInspected, Model.QtyInspected)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.MassOff, Model.MassOff)

    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.Product, Model.Product)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.Variety, Model.Variety)
    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.Supplier, Model.Supplier)

    @Html.HiddenFor(y => y.Defects, Model.Defects)

    <input type="submit" value="Email" class="pull-right btn btn-default" />
}
```

And when I step through the program, I can see that the properties `Pallet` and `Defects` are definitely populated when the view is created (they contain objects of type `Pallet` and `List<QCItem>` respectively).

However, when I click the `Email` button and step through the code in the controller, I can see that these properties both contain `null`, even though the other properties are all populated:

```
public class SampleController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send(Sample sample)
    {
        return View(sample);
    }
}
```

Where do I begin debugging this issue? I feel like there is no possible step in between where the properties can be set to null.

I tried removing the `hiddenField`s for all the other properties just to make sure they are being set in this form, and sure enough that causes an empty `Sample` object to be sent to the controller.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why are you passing in the value as `htmlAttributes`? I would start to look at the HTML and see if that is alright.

Comment: First of all your just need `@Html.HiddenFor(y => y.QCDate)` - the 2nd parameter adds `htmlAttributes`

Comment: If you have not populated the value of `PONo` in the GET method (i.e. `model.PONo = model.Pallet.Grv.PONo;`), then it will return `null`. But what is the point of a form with all hidden inputs - you cannot edit anything

Comment: And you cannot create a hidden input for a complex object or collection - look at the html your generating - `@Html.HiddenFor(y => y.Defects)` will generate `value="System.Collection.List<QCItem>"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just want to pass the entire model to a new view, so that the user can see the details, and the new view will also contain a form for them to add further notes (all of which will be sent together with the `Sample` data in an email)

Comment: The properties are populated, the inputs aren't. You can only post scalar values, not complex types.

Comment: You send the ID of the object and get it again in the POST method

Comment: If `Defects` is `IEnumerable` complex object, you need to use indexer with `for` loop to bind values contained with it, not directly assigned to `HiddenFor`. I don't see your intent by using `HiddenFor` for all form values (they're not shown in view page) - just use `TextBoxFor` and `readonly` HTML attributes to prevent edit with specific text input.